Admissible values for non diagonal elements of correlation matrix
Preparing for possible job market interview questions I was reading some questions on the site.
Regarding this question with its solution interview questions

Question
Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a $n\times n$ covariance matrix such that all diagonal elements are equal to 1, and the non-diagonal ones to $\rho$ with $-1\leq\rho\leq1$. Which range of values is admissible for $\rho$?

Solution 1
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables with unit variance and pairwise correlation $\rho$ for any $i\not= j$. Let $Y:=\sum_iX_i$ then:
\begin{align}
    \notag
    V\left(Y\right)
    &=\sum_{i=1}^nV\left(X_i\right)+\sum_{i\not=j}Cov(X_i,X_j)
    \\
    &=n+n(n-1)\rho
\end{align}
The variance of $Y$ is positive, therefore:
\begin{align}
n+n(n-1)\rho\geq0 
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \boxed{\rho\geq\frac{1}{1-n}}
\end{align}

I do not understand why $V(Y)$ is equal to $n+n(n-1)\rho$. Shouldn't be equal to $n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\rho$ since $\sum_{i\not=j}Cov(X_i,X_j) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\rho$ ?
This would change the final solution to
\begin{align}
n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\rho\geq0 
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \boxed{\rho\geq\frac{2}{1-n}}
\end{align}
What Am I missing?

The title could be improved, I tried.

In your example,
$$
\begin{align}
V(\sum X_i) &= \sum V(x_i)+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n V(X_i,X_j)\\
&=n+2\sum_i^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n\rho\\
&=n+2\rho \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&=n+n(n-1)\rho
\end{align}
$$
as was the original.
IMHO, a better and cleaner way to obtain this result is by imposing the condition that the corresponding covariance matrix is positive (semi)definite, i.e.
$$
\lambda_{min}(\Sigma)\geq 0
$$
For a $n\times n$ matrix of the type
$$
\Sigma=(1-\rho)\mathbf{I}+\rho\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ the identity matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ a vector of ones, the eigenvalues are $1-\rho$ and $(n-1)\rho+1$. Thus we require
$$
(n-1)\rho+1\geq0 \Rightarrow \boxed{\rho\geq\frac{1}{1-n}}
$$
Derivation
Using the matrix determinant lemma, we can solve for the eigenvalues as:
$$
\begin{align}
0&=\mathrm{det}\left(\Sigma-\lambda\mathbf{I}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{det}\left((1-\rho)\mathbf{I}+\rho\mathbf{11^T}-\lambda\mathbf{I}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{det}\left((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}+\rho\mathbf{11^T}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{det}\left((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}\left(\mathbf{I}+\frac{\rho}{1-\rho-\lambda}\mathbf{11^T}\right)\right)\\
&=\mathrm{det}\left((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}\right)\mathrm{det}\left(\mathbf{I}+\frac{\rho}{1-\rho-\lambda}\mathbf{11^T}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\rho-\lambda\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{n\rho}{1-\rho-\lambda}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\rho-\lambda\right)^{n}+n\rho\left(1-\rho-\lambda\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\left(1-\rho-\lambda\right)^{n-1}\left(1+(n-1)\rho-\lambda\right)
\end{align}
$$
and hence $\lambda_1=1-\rho$ and $\lambda_2=1+(n-1)\rho$.

Yes, I also thought the positive definiteness was the way to go with the same disection of Covariance matrrix as you made.
